# How to see indexes for a database or table in Google Spanner?

Tags: sql, cloud, google-cloud-spanner

How do I see if my database has any indexes on it?

How about for a specific table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to find the exising indexes.

1. GCP console UI: [Pantheon](https://pantheon.corp.google.com/) , navigate to Spanner -> Instance -> Database -> Table. Indexes can be found under 'Indexes' sub-tab.
2. Command line [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/information-schema#indexes) query.

   `gcloud spanner databases execute-sql {DATABAES_NAME} --instance={INSTANCE_NAME} --sql="SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INDEXES`"